# gnome-shell or xorg not visible under nvidia-smi processes

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, xorg, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 23.10. I have NVIDIA GT 730, which is a legacy card now. While installation, the GDM would not appear, I was only greeted with a black screen. I installed using Safe Graphics Mode. And after installation, I installed Nvidia display driver 470, which is the latest driver from my GPU. I am using Xorg, and under Settings>About>System Details, I can see that Graphics is "NVIDIA GT730" but I don't think it's gnome is using my GPU for display rendering.  Everything's very laggy and slow.

Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`:
[image]

It shows no running process, but while searching for the solution I found that it shows Xorg and gnome-shell under processes for others, meaning GPU is being used for rendering the gnome-shell.

I have tried reinstalling the drivers, what shall I do now ??

Output of `sudo X -version`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.7 
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux Dhruv 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:59:49 UTC 2023 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic root=UUID=49c34387-1b4a-45d8-a53a-4f15baeb775d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version
```

Output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "LoadModule"`:

```
(II) LoadModule: "glx" 8.725] 
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia" 8.735] 
(II) LoadModule: "nouveau" 8.739] 
(II) LoadModule: "modesetting" 8.740] 
(II) LoadModule: "fbdev" 8.741] 
(II) LoadModule: "vesa" 8.748] 
(II) LoadModule: "fb" [ 8.748] 
(II) LoadModule: "wfb" [ 8.749] 
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac" 8.751] 
(II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw" 8.753] 
(II) LoadModule: glxserver_nvidia"
(II) LoadModule: "dri2" 9.853] 
(II) LoadModule: "libinput"
```

Comment: You should check which display driver Xorg is using. You can find out in the Xorg log file.

Comment: sudo X -version

Comment: @DanielB update the answer with the output. Both `nouveau` and `nvidia` drivers are being loaded, could that be the issue?

Comment: It’s not great, but only one module can win. Looking at _LoadModule_ log lines is not enough. You must read the entire log.